# Исключение при запуске программы

Tags: android

При установке приложения и открытии первый раз такие исключения выбразываются в лог. Что это означает?

```
E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 32456 of [bda77dda96]
E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:32456: (2) open(/data/data/ru.test.dbtest/databases/dbaza.db) - 
E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/ru.test.dbtest/databases/dbaza.db'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
at ru.test.dbtest.data.DBHeler.checkDataBase(DBHeler.java:65)
at ru.test.dbtest.data.DBHeler.createDataBase(DBHeler.java:41)
at ru.test.dbtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:80)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: ` Failed to open database '/data/data/ru.test.dbtest/databases/dbaza.db'.`

Comment: Но приложение запускается, и данные считываются из БД. Второй раз когда открывается приложение такого нет.

Comment: База данных хранится в отдельном файле, или создается в первый раз?

Comment: Если вы копируете файл базы данных в папку Assest то при вставке за именем БД уберите .db

Comment: private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbaza.db";  тут имеете ввиду убрать?